# Android - SharedPreferences - Atualização do App [Dúvida]

Tags: android

Eu tenho um programa xpto na versão 9.0.8 e, nessa versão, eu adicionei uma SharedPreference que armazena um valor correspondente a versão atual do app para realizar algumas tarefas.

Quando eu for atualizar esse programa para a versão 9.0.9 em um dispositivo que continha a versão 9.0.8, a tag correspondente ao valor da versão (9.0.8) permanecerá salvo na memória do aparelho?

Comment: O SharedPreferences é planejado para que armazene informações do aplicativo, e não de sua versão, sendo assim, teríamos que fazer login a cada atualização em um aplicativo, caso este guarde informações de usuário.
Sendo assim, mudar versão não altera em nada os dados armazenados.

Comment: Eu armazenaria a versão atual do aplicativo para automatizar algumas tarefas, essa verificação seria feita apenas uma vez, por isso capturar a versão do App seria útil no meu caso.

Comment: Bom, ai você terá que fazer a verificação ao iniciar a Activity principal, que vai ser iniciada ao iniciar o app, a qual buscará o BuildConfig e comparará com a informação no SharedPreference.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Assis.

Comment: De nada Pedro, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Então, ela ficará salva sim, porém pode ter algum erro desconhecido e ela não será salva. Comigo isso nunca ocorreu nas apis novas.

Tem que levar em consideração os mesmos package name, e também o mesmo nome atribuído a sharedpreferences.

Apartir da Api 23 é possível deixar de maneira explícita o backup dos dados para isso inclua no manifest, dentro de application:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```